# How to export a variable to another python file

Tags: python, file, variables, export

Hi all I am creating a game that allows the user to export their progress to another file which can be loaded back up again once they come back. I am wondering if there is a way to export multiple variables to a different file, which will then change the file in the computer's memory. I have a way to import the variables, I just need some help with the exporting part, thank you for your help, Darren.

Comment: Save to a JSON or Pickle file, and have the other script load from the file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try store the users progress data in JSON file.
In python it`s pretty easy, you just need to use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library.

First you should import lib

```py
import json
```

For example the player`s data looks like this

```py
player_data = {
    'username': 'Nemo',
    'xp': 1000,
    'armor': {
        'name': 'Kaer Morhen armor',
        'weight': 1.57
    }
}
```

Than you can easely export this data to JSON file

```py
with open("data_file.json", "w") as wf:
    json.dump(player_data, wf)
```

And import it back

```py
with open("data_file.json", "r") as rf:
    player_data = json.load(rf)
```

I hope it would be helpful for you :)